# how to load suggestions in searchview from database?

Tags: android, database

I have SearchView which loads suggestions from array when I write any word, How to load suggestions from database not array?

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
searchView.setVoiceSearch(false);
searchView.setCursorDrawable(R.drawable.custom_cursor);
searchView.setEllipsize(true);
searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        return false;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        //Do some magic
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

by changing arraylist to array the code work

```
db =  DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    db.open();
    ArrayList<Product> products = db.getMiavit();
    final String[] suggestions = new String[products.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        suggestions[i] = products.get(i).getPRODUCTS();
    }
  searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setVoiceSearch(false);
    searchView.setCursorDrawable(R.drawable.custom_cursor);
  searchView.setSuggestions(suggestions);



    searchView.setEllipsize(true);
    db.close();
```